# I cannot upload the .p12 certificate for on the OneSignal Website

Tags: ios, onesignal

I cannot upload my .p12 certificate on the OneSignal website. I have tried using Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Arc but I am met with the same error message, "Something went wrong while we tried to save the platform information. Please try again". Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rubRa.jpg)

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. I was able to solve the problem. I was not creating the certificate in the correct manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I have noticed, if you used a `certSigningRequest` to sign your certificate, you `.p12` file would be rejected.
So to do this you need to

1. Generate 2048-bit RSA private key: `openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048`
2. Generate a Certificate Signing Request: `openssl req -new -sha256 -key mykey.key -out mykey.csr`
3. You will first revoke the existing certificate and then create a new one using this new `.csr` file.
4. After you create the certificate download it
5. Convert the certificate: `openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in aps_development.cer -out aps_development.pem`
6. Build the PKCS#12: `openssl pkcs12 -inkey aps_development.key -in aps_development.pem -export -out aps_development.p12`

This final `.p12` file is what you will upload to your onesignal.

Comment: Can I create the certificate using the "Request a certificate from a certificate authority" from Keychain Access? Thats how I created it the first time, but I did it incorrectly somehow.

Comment: I don't think you did it incorrectly.

Comment: I don't know what I did incorrectly but it is working now after following your steps again. Thanks, @Denzel. And sorry for replying so late.